# Generating raster with its spatial reference from array (or matrix) by using pyqgis?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, array

I used arcgis to generate rasters from txt files by a certain python api,but i am not familiar with qgis,and now i need generate some rasters from txt files by using pyqgis.

The resulting rasters should be with their spatial reference so i can do some calculation across rasters with different spatial extents.

Comment: How is the content of your txt-file structured? Is it just a table of values or does it come with some kind of spatial reference?

Comment: thakns.it contains just the values of the raster, but i know each values' latitude and longitute.By the way, my development environment is on windows